# Segmentation fault initialising an array

Tags: c

The following program produces a segmentation fault, and I'm not sure why. `malloc` succeeds, so it doesn't seem to be an initialisation error, but for some reason, it segfaults when I access the 253900th element. The array is only 4 * 1e6 bytes, or a about a Megabyte.

**This does produce a lot of output**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *long_array(size_t N) {
    int *arr = (int *) malloc(N);
    if (arr == NULL) { printf("could not malloc"); exit(1); }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf(".. %ld ", i);
        arr[i] =  10;
    }
    printf("done with loop\n");
    return arr;
}

int main(void) {
    int *arr = long_array(1000000);
    printf("%d", arr[5050]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this with `gcc -std=c99` and run the output to see the final few numbers printed before the segfault:

```
253899 .. 253900 .. 2
segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

I don't understand why accessing a particular index is causing the segmentation fault. I can guess that I must be accessing a memory location outside of my processes address space, but this seems like a bug if I successfully allocated the memory from within my address space.

Comment: Your array is 1Mb roughly, but you're trying to access elements beyond that. When allocating, you're not taking into account the size of `int`. Use `int *arr = malloc(N*sizeof(*arr));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(int)*N)` instead of `malloc(N)`.
Otherwise you'd get an array of N bytes, not N integers.

Comment: Oh jeez, I just read about that. Sorry, brain farts. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 int *arr = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the problem here is that your did not consider the size of an integer
while allocating memory. You just allocated :

```
int *arr=(int *)malloc(N);
```

here you just allocated size of N but you have to consider size of integer in your machine.
If you allocate just 10000000 size of memory and sizeof(int) in you machine is 4 then it can just access (10000000/4) memory .........
So you have to allocate memory like:

```
int *arr=(int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int))
```

or

```
int *arr=(int *)malloc(N*sizeof(*arr));
```